# taking advantages of grub

Tags: ubuntu, grub

I'm thinking to install Ubuntu on my laptop just to have grub in order to boot from the EISA partition. What do you think? Do you think that might be a good idea? How will affect grub or ubuntu the EISA partition ?

TY

Comment: what's your laptop brand ? if you've any driver and some stuffs(for Win), you could take advantages of grub. but I think it won't be quite easy. Take a look at this article http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4622

Comment: @mgpyone that article is SUPER old (2001) and doesn't really help too much today. GRUB2 will be a straight forward install and works well as a bootloader. Personally I get rid of those extra partitions, as they are just a waste of space.